Am I going about statistical significance testing for weighted categorical survey data the right way?
I created a (fictional) dataset that contains individuals' car colors and their level of agreement to the question "I enjoy driving fast". The survey includes three car colors (red, black, and white) and six possible responses to the question (strongly agree, agree, slightly Agree, slightly disagree, disagree, and strongly disagree). In addition, each respondent has a corresponding weight value; the weights and original response counts both add up to 1,059 (the number of respondents).
Here's a sample of the original survey data:
     Car_Color    Weight Enjoy_Driving_Fast  Count  Response_Sort_Map
0        Black  1.787571              Agree      1                  1
1        White  0.351450  Strongly Disagree      1                  5
2        Black  1.647582     Strongly Agree      1                  0
3        Black  1.143698              Agree      1                  1
4        Black  1.766930     Strongly Agree      1                  0
...        ...       ...                ...    ...                ...
1054     White  1.336661  Strongly Disagree      1                  5
1055     Black  0.623541  Strongly Disagree      1                  5
1056       Red  1.775047     Slightly Agree      1                  2
1057     Black  0.127984     Strongly Agree      1                  0
1058       Red  1.063730  Strongly Disagree      1                  5

I had the following goals for my analysis, which I chose to complete in Python:

First, I wanted to see whether the distribution of responses to this question varied by car color.

Next, I wanted to evaluate for which pairs of car colors these responses differ.  (For instance, did drivers of black and red cars provide different sets of responses? What about drivers of red and white cars?)

Finally, for car color pairs that did differ significantly, I wanted to see which responses produced significantly different percentages. (It's possible, for example, that similar percentages of drivers of red and white cars responded 'strongly agree' to the question, but different percentages responded 'strongly disagree.')


Here are the steps I took to answer these questions. I'd like to confirm that these choices were methodologically correct--and if not, what I should be doing instead.

I added up the sum of the respondent weights by car color and response type, then performed scipy's chi2_contingency() test.

Here's the table on which I performed the test:
                    Weight_Black  Weight_Red  Weight_White
Enjoy_Driving_Fast                                        
Strongly Agree        193.613523  149.694542     67.837371
Agree                  97.155614   59.284623     73.892275
Slightly Agree         34.585260   40.090462     32.097230
Slightly Disagree      20.269425   12.510517     18.881291
Disagree               15.611271    9.149987     11.103944
Strongly Disagree      45.764907   40.269868    137.187889

And here's my chi^2 code along with its results:
chi2, p, dof, ex = chi2_contingency( df_car_survey_wide_weights_only, lambda_="log-likelihood")
chi2, p, dof, ex
(np.float64(139.49198358844737),
 np.float64(5.355832944633564e-25),
 10,
 array([[158.01340166, 120.74242731, 132.3896068 ],
        [ 88.5225045 ,  67.64250344,  74.16750377],
        [ 41.03549739,  31.35636287,  34.38109241],
        [ 19.85469492,  15.17152363,  16.63501466],
        [ 13.78388796,  10.53265149,  11.54866289],
        [ 85.79001356,  65.55453125,  71.87811947]]))

This p value (5.3558 * 10^-25) is well below 0.05, so I concluded that there was a significant difference in response distributions among drivers of red, black, and white cars.
Question: Is this method of just summing up the weights a valid method of performing a weighted chi square test in Python? It appears that no weighted chi squared test exists within Python, but perhaps this workaround is acceptable.

I next performed similar chi squared tests for each pair of car colors. For instance, here's my code and output for the red vs. black test:

chi2, p, dof, ex = chi2_contingency( df_car_survey_wide_weights_only[['Weight_Black', 'Weight_Red']])
chi2, p, dof, ex
(np.float64(6.3433989824883845),
 np.float64(0.27422376264989284),
 5,
 array([[194.60498954, 148.70307555],
        [ 88.67851876,  67.76171827],
        [ 42.33010996,  32.34561228],
        [ 18.58138777,  14.19855429],
        [ 14.03597767,  10.72528024],
        [ 48.76901629,  37.26575938]]))

In this case, the p value was well above 0.05, so I concluded that the differences in red-car- and black-car-drivers' responses were not statistically significant.
Question: should I be applying a Bonferroni correction of x 3 to each of these tests, as I'm making three car color comparisons in total? (red vs. black, red vs. white, and white vs. black)

After completing these tests, I found that the responses of red- and white-car drivers differed significantly, as did those from drivers of white and black cars. However, I also wanted to see which response options (strongly agree, slightly disagree, etc.) had different proportions among these groups. (For example, 48.13% of red-car drivers responded with 'strongly agree' whereas only 19.89% of white-car drivers did; I wanted to see whether this difference in proportions was statistically significant.

To perform these tests, I went with the proportions_ztest() that Statsmodels offers. To prepare for this test, I created a new table called df_z. The top row of this table shows the sum of the weights of red and white car drivers who responded 'strongly agree' to the first question, and the bottom row shows the sum of the weights of all red and white car drivers.
       Weight_Red_Strongly Agree  Weight_White_Strongly Agree
Count                 149.694542                    67.837371
Total                 311.000000                   341.000000

Here's my proportions_ztest and its corresponding output:
print(proportions_ztest(count = df_z.loc['Count'],  nobs = df_z.loc['Total']
(np.float64(7.638355155418083), np.float64(2.2001427667960553e-14))
In this case, the p value (2.2*10^-14) was statistically significant. However, I'm thinking that I need to use a Bonferroni correction here of either 6 (the number of response categories) or 18 (the number of categories * the number of car color comparisons I conducted earlier) in order to prevent my false positive rate from getting artificially inflated. Which of these would be best to use?
And, as with the chi squared question, I'd like to figure out whether using the weights as a basis for my proportions rather than the response counts is a valid means of performing a weighted proportions Z test in Python.
Finally: I'm basing these analyses off of the respondents' weight values rather than treating each row equally. Would this cause any issues within my significance testing? (The weights and respondent counts both add up to 1059.)

Welcome to Cross Validated! This is a bit outside my comfort zone, but this answer from an individual who wrote and maintains the R survey package might provide some guidance. I understand that the Rao-Scott test is typically used with contingency tables from weighted survey data, instead of a standard chi-square test. Also, the Bonferroni correction is too strict; the Holm modification provides the same protection with greater power.

You should clarify what kind of weight it is and how they have been calculated. Regarding a Python implementation of methods to work with survey weights, it is incorrect to say that it does not exist. The package samplics allow you to work with survey weights. Here's an example with contingency tables: https://samplics-org.github.io/samplics/pages/categorical_tabulation.html#two-way-tabulation-cross-tabulation

Thank you for letting me know about the samplics library--it looks very promising. The weights in this dataset were randomly-generated numbers; they were created in order to represent the weight columns that often appear within actual survey data.
